# Can't use Lapack: Class 'Lapack' not found in

Tags: php, apache, centos, lapack

After installing lapack via:

```
yum install lapack lapack-devel
```

and restarting httpd service I still get

```
Fatal error: Class 'Lapack' not found in /var/www/html/metody_obliczeniowe/proj1/3.php on line 135
```

when trying to use the example from:
http://php.net/manual/en/lapack.solvelinearequation.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the lapack extension.

```
# pecl install lapack
```